# Cannot call setValue for element using Appium, Javascript and webdriverio

Tags: webdriver-io, appium-android

I am using Appium, UIAutomator2, webdriverio and JavaScript to test an app which is running on a virtual device.

I search for an element and set (or in this case clear) its value.

Using class selector it works fine.

```js
const codeField = await driver.$("android.widget.EditText");
await codeField.clearValue();
```

But I would like to find the element by id, so I have this:

```js
const codeField = await driver.findElement("id", "de.abcdef.ghijkl:id/activation_code_input");
await codeField.clearValue();
```

It results in:

```
webdriver: COMMAND findElement("id", "de.abcdef.ghijkl:id/activation_code_input")

webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/f0a6844b-55e0-468d-b165-14cb219e55f7/element

webdriver: DATA {using: 'id', value: 'de.abcdef.ghijkl:id/activation_code_input'}

webdriver: RESULT {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf: '5d56ef1d-0036-4ecf-8b26-f060e290510b', ELEMENT: '5d56ef1d-0036-4ecf-8b26-f060e290510b'}
```

and finally, when it should set the value of the field

```
TypeError: codeField.clearValue is not a function
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the webdriverio is not able to resolve the retrieved element correctly when I use findElement("id", ...) or findElement("xpath", ...). As I would like to address the element by id resp. resource-id instead of the class, I could solve it by passing the resource-id using xpath syntax

```js
const codeField = await driver.$('//*[@resource-id="de.abcdef.ghijkl:id/activation_code_input"]');
```

Comment: Absolutely, But did anyone find the root cause of this behavior?